# Android c2dm No message received

Tags: android, android-c2dm

i've implemented the c2dm on my phone application. The c2dm application does receive message a few days ago, but afterawhile it stops receiving any message.

When pushing to the google c2dm link, i got the response "id=0:1325918022124320%6c25a09400000031". with the header ok, is  there any wrong here?

I am using the following to send message

```
   public void SendMessage(string registrationId, string data, string sAuth)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        NameValueCollection postFieldNameValue = new NameValueCollection();
        postFieldNameValue.Add("registration_id", registrationId);
        postFieldNameValue.Add("collapse_key", "1");
        postFieldNameValue.Add("delay_while_idle", "0");
        postFieldNameValue.Add("data.payload", data);
        string postData = ConstructQueryString(postFieldNameValue);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "GoogleLogin auth=" + sAuth);

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        HttpStatusCode responseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;
        if (responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
        {
            Response.Write("Unauthorized - need new token");
        }
        else if (!responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
            Response.Write("Response from web service not OK :");
            Response.Write(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        }

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseLine = reader.ReadLine();
        reader.Close();
        Response.Write(responseLine); 

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

twice check with your google registration key. I think it might changed somehow thats y you dont able to receive any massage. make sure that key on both side server as well client are same.

Comment: ask further if you have any query

Comment: hi, i've tried mannually entering the registartion key and its still not working. i even rebooted my phone and re-register

Comment: register device with all new fresh gmail account and then register with c2dm. after that you will get registation id , pass this same id to your server side code to sent message. i  think you have issue with key

Comment: register device as in sending the email intent to the server and getting back the "registration id" from the broadcast? Thanks

Comment: Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
     registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
        registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "xyz@gmail.com");
        this.startService(registrationIntent);

Comment: you have to write above code in your application to get registration Id from google , which you have to pass to server from sending massage to device

Comment: ya i already did, just wants to comfirm :). the receiving works few days ago but stopped working suddenly :(. got to try your recommendation to re-register.

Comment: now you have to check your code starting from the scratch. make sure that device net is working perfectly, Email Id is Active or not, you also have to check server side code and make sure that both keys are same, print all the responses in logcat so that you can get some idea

Comment: Tried, re-registering and again it doesn't work. 

even though my  (HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription gives me response "OK". could it be my android application? it is able to receive registaration id just doesn't able to receive message

Comment: yes i have allowed all the permission. i used the same application and it worked a few days ago :(, but it stopped suddenly. Is there any other related problem? such as using another sim card?

Comment: i'm quite sure teh mobile application is the same app that works previosuly. could it be the web app. can you check what i have written on top and check if there is any problem with the posting of message to c2dm

Comment: haha, not sure why it worked again. i re-registerd my inital email and it worked :)